# Contract Address cannot receive ETH

Tags: ethereum, contract, erc20

I have tried many times but cannot transfer ETH to Contract Address.
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xe9d0430dea9b84a9e32801d6e6072175fd48fb85

Errors such as:
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [out of gas]
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]

I tried increasing the Gas Limit but all failed, I'm really confused and stuck. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your contract needs to contain either the `fallback()` or the `receive()` function to be able to receive ETH.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract JetToken is ERC20 {
    // TODO rest of your code

    receive() external payable {
        // you can leave this function body empty
    }
}
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/contracts.html#receive-ether-function